# Elasticsearch query with intermediate results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and I have problem querying it efficiently. I have following types of objects:

- `Teacher`
- `Class`
- `TeacherClass` (with integer fields `teacher_id` and `class_id`)
- `Event` (with integer field `teacher_class_id`)

So the structure looks like this:

```
___________       _______________      _________
| Teacher |_____/| TeacherClass |\_____| Class |
|_________|     \|______________|/     |_______|
                        |
                        |
                    ___/_\___                     
                    | Event |
                    |_______|
```

I want to get the number of events associated with given teacher. Currently I'm doing this with two queries:

- search query on `TeacherClass` (to get an array of `TeacherClass` ids)
- count query on `Event` (to count events with `teacher_class_id` equal to one of the values in the array).

Is there a way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword here is **denormalization**. You need to denormalize your data so that each document contains the following fields:

```
{
    "teacher_id": 1,
    "teacher_name": "John Math",
    "class_id": 2,
    "class_name": "Math",
    "event_id": 3,
    "event_name": "My Event"
}
```

You can then aggregate your data with a `terms` aggregation on `teacher_id` and see how many different events you have using a `value_count` sub-aggregation on `event_id`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "teachers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "teacher_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "events": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "event_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to do it without modifying data structures?

Comment: Your data structure is not optimal in my opinion. When modeling your data you need to think about how you're going to query it and model your data accordingly. There's no point in mapping 1:1 with what you have in an RDBMS. ES is a different beast and requires a different way of thinking about data. If I may suggest a good article: https://bonsai.io/2016/01/11/ideal-elasticsearch-cluster

Comment: Do you need more info?